# perl Getopt::Long::GetOptions usage

Tags: shell, perl, command-line-tool

I wanted to use `Getopt::Long::GetOptions` for getting command line options to the script.

I have a requirement like this:

```
perl script.pl -c <name1> -c <name2> -m <name3> argument
```

Here we have option flags `-c` and `-m`m which are optional, and `argument` is mandatory.

Can anyone point out the correct usage for `GetOptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code and result.

https://gist.github.com/kyanny/5634832

If you want to know more about how to handle multiple values option, see documantation: http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values

One more thing, Getopt::Long::GetOptions does not provide the way to handle mandatory options. You should check if the mandatory options are in the @ARGV and raise Exceptions, etc. in your hand.

Comment: Thanks Kyanny your answer helps. I have another question here I want to use "+" as an option ? Can I do GetOptions( '+=f' => sub {$plus = "true"} )

Answer (score 4):

From the [`Getopt::Long` documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long#GetOptions-does-not-return-a-false-result-when-an-option-is-not-supplied):

> #### `GetOptions` does not return a false result when an option is not supplied
>
> That's why they're called 'options'.

In other words, if you are expecting a mandatory parameter, you need to explicitly check for it outside of the `GetOptions` call.

---

If argument is meant to be part of `@ARGV` and not the options, use `--` to signal the end of options. In the example below, the script would access `argument` via `$ARGV[0]`:

```
perl script.pl -c <name1> -c <name2> -m <name3> -- argument
```

Comment: Alternatively you can set `pass_through` to let all unknown parameters go to `@ARGV`. `use Getopt::Long qw(:config pass_through)` but beware as this does affect "type checking" on option values.